# Unable to load placepicker using GMSPlacePickerViewController

Tags: swift

I am trying to access near by places using placePicker and `GMSPlacePickerViewController` methods . But my console is saying that places API is not enabled in Google Console . But , when i check there , it is enabled . Not knowing the exact issue . Requesting for some help .

> Places SDK error: Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-9
>   "The Places API service for iOS is not enabled. See the developer's
>   guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) to learn
>   how to set up the Places SDK for iOS or the migration guide
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration) if you
>   are migrating from an earlier version."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The Places API service for iOS is
>   not enabled. See the developer's guide
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) to learn how to
>   set up the Places SDK for iOS or the migration guide
>   (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration) if you
>   are migrating from an earlier version.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x60400084eaf0 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60400084e820 {Error
>   Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "Access Not
>   Configured. Google Places API for iOS has not been used in project
>   1047578903605 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/placesios.googleapis.com/overview?project=1047578903605
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

```
    @IBAction func buttonCurrentAddTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
        let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)
        placePicker.delegate = self

        present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Place name \(String(describing: place.name))")
        self.currentAddressTextField.text = place.name
    }

    func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // In your own app you should handle this better, but for the demo we are just going to log
        // a message.
        NSLog("An error occurred while picking a place: \(error)")
    }

    func placePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController) {
        // Dismiss the place picker, as it cannot dismiss itself.
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("No place selected")
        self.currentAddressTextField.text = "No place selected"
    }
```

Expecting to load near by places when i click on textField .

Comment: Follow the guides provided in your question. I would start with enabling the places api for iOS.

Comment: facing same issues, did you find any solution ?